# Looping through array to create mysqli query

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through a PHP array to build my query:

```
$args = array("this", "that", "other");

$arg_string = '';

foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    $arg_string .= "&& StockMastID LIKE '%{".$value."}%' ";
}

$arg_string = substr($arg_string, 3); // Remove && from first $args

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE `$arg_string`");
```

So, theoretically, the query should now be:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE StockMastID LIKE '%{this}%' && StockMastID LIKE '%{that}%' && StockMastID LIKE '%{other}%'");
```

This is not working as I am getting a `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object` error when executing the query. The query executes fine if I manually type it out instead of using the loop, so there must either be an error in the `foreach` syntax, or something with the quotes or ticks around `$arg_string` in the query, but I can't figure out what it is.

NOTE: Or, should I abandon this and go for `REGEXP` instead? If so, how would that look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use a prepared statement, but you have a problem here:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE `$arg_string`");
                                                     ^           ^
```

These characters will be part of your query string. The backticks will cause your query to fail completely, the problem that you are having now. Backticks are for identifiers like table and column names.

I assume that the `{ ... }` curly quotes are intentional as you seem to have them in your working query as well. If not, you should remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 errors:

1. Remove the `{` `}` from your query string.

   So change this:

   ```
   $arg_string .= "&& StockMastID LIKE '%{".$value."}%' ";
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   $arg_string .= "&& StockMastID LIKE '%".$value."%' ";
   ```
2. unecessary `'` quotes:

   change this:

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE `$arg_string`"
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE $arg_string"
   ```